# JBOSS - How to prevent multiple instances of a configuration to start

Tags: jboss

We are using JBOSS AS.

We have created a our own configuration (similar to minimum, default)

The user can use the run.sh to start the application.

I don't want to allow the user to start multiple instances of the same configuration to run.

Let me know if there is any way to do this.

Comment: you mean not to allow multiple instances to run on different ports?

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't mention any information about your JBoss environment, however in practice if you try to start two instances of the application server on the same machine (using the same configuration), the second one will fail, raising a [Bind Exception](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-configuration/solving-javanetbindexception-address-already-in-use-jvm_bind).
If you provide some more details I'll try to help you more.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

In your script add a line that put the PID in a file, then if the pid file is here when you launch you script it will stop.